# Download created pdf on load and redirect

Tags: php, jsp, pdf

I'm trying to make a product overview page where a user can download an invoice. However this invoice needs to be generated to the specific product.

At the moment the way i do this is to navigate to invoice.jsp which sends the ID to the server which in turn creates the invoice.pdf, after this is created the user can push a button to download the just created file.

However I would like to skip the last step and trigger the download as soon as the page is loaded and redirect back to the orderoveriew.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Make an iframe on orderoveriew.jsp with the pdf code. Just remember to set

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
```

and it will download automatically, other methods might not work with pop-up blockers.